# Передача данных на другую страницу

Tags: php

Здравствуйте.
Хочу реализовать следующее: пользователь заходит на страницу, нажимает кнопку, после нажатия кнопки он попадает на страницу, на которой ему передается значение переменно *$err* и его сразу же бросает на изначальную страницу, но уже на этой странице пользователю выводит значение переменной *$err* до тех пор, покуда пользователь не обновит страницу.
Как реализовать перенаправление я знаю, а вот как осуществить передачу значения из переменной у меня вариантов нет. 
Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если Вам нужен сугубо `php` вариант, используйте [cookies](http://php.net/manual/ru/features.cookies.php) или  [sessions](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php) для сохранения небольших данных.

Пример использования сессий:

```
// Включаем сессии
session_start();
// Запись в сессию
$_SESSION['msg'] = 'My message here.';
// Чтение из сессии
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
// Удаление значения
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
```

*Если у пользователя в браузере отключены `cookies`, то этот способ работать не будет.*

А также, Вы можете сохранить данные (даже большие) в [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) или в [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), при помощи *JavaScript*, которые не требуют `cookies`.

Answer (score 0):

например, передавать параметром:

```
http://u.r.l/return?param=value
```

а в скрипте, обрабатыващем этот запрос, выводить `value` в нужное место.

Comment: хм,   а другого варианта нету? не хотелось бы портить вид ссылки в адресной строке)

Comment: ознакомьтесь, пожалуйста, с различиями в методах передачи параметров [`post`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#POST) и [`get`](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#GET).

Comment: *не хотелось бы портить вид ссылки в адресной строке* — насколько мне известно, элегантного, простого и универсального решения (на `php`) — нет. для поиска не-элегантных, не-простых и не-универсальных решений можно воспользоваться, например, такой поисковой строкой: «php redirect with post data».